# I want to insert values for Ranks column on bases of other column required condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @count int = 0

while (@count != 3156)
begin
    while(ErrorCode not like 'm%')
    begin
        insert into #temp(Ranks) 
        values(@count)  
    end

    set @count = @count + 1
end
```

I have a temp table with 3 columns `ErrorCode`, `ErrorCount` and `Ranks` and I have to insert same values in `Ranks` column whenever initial value of `ErrorCode` is repeated. I have NULL in `Ranks` column now:

```
ErrorCode               ErrorCount            Ranks
----------------------------------------------------
module_position           A1_16__1               1
head_id HZ0C1              000877                1
start_dt            2018-09-10 00:18:27          1
module_position           A2_16__1               2
head_id HZ0C1              000878                2
start_dt            2018-09-10 00:18:27          2
```

I want output as above for the `Ranks` column. Note, that the initial value is always `module_position` whenever I have to insert new rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [RowID] INT
   ,[ErrorCode] VARCHAR(32)
   ,[ErrorCount] VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([RowID], [ErrorCode], [ErrorCount])
VALUES (1, 'module_position', 'A1_16__1')
      ,(2, 'head_id HZ0C1', '   000877')
      ,(3, 'start_dt', ' 2018-09-10 00:18:27')
      ,(4, 'module_position', 'A2_16__1')
      ,(5, 'head_id HZ0C1', '   000878')
      ,(6, 'start_dt', ' 2018-09-10 00:18:27')

SELECT [ErrorCode]
      ,[ErrorCount]
      ,SUM(IIF([ErrorCode] = 'module_position', 1, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY [RowID])
FROM @DataSource;
```

Please, note that you have an certain way to order the rows correctly. You cannot assume that reading them from the table without specifying unique criteria for ordering will always give you the same and the desire result.

In the example above I am using a `RowID` column. If you have a creation date for example, you can sort by it.

If you do not sort the rows, you can end with `head_id` of one error to be grouped with another.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempErrorCode
(   id int identity(1,1) not null,
   [ErrorCode] VARCHAR(50)
   ,[ErrorCount] VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #TempErrorCode ([ErrorCode], [ErrorCount])
VALUES ('module_position', 'A1_16__1')
      ,('head_id HZ0C1', '   000877')
      ,('start_dt', ' 2018-09-10 00:18:27')
      ,('module_position', 'A2_16__1')
      ,('head_id HZ0C1', '   000878')
      ,('start_dt', ' 2018-09-10 00:18:27')

ALTER TABLE #TempErrorCode ADD RankVal INT

SELECT * INTO #TempRank FROM(  
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ErrorCode ORDER BY ErrorCode desc) as NewRank FROM #TempErrorCode
)a

--SELECT * FROM #TempRank

UPDATE A    
  SET RankVal = RA.NewRank   
from #TempErrorCode A
  INNER JOIN #TempRank RA
    ON A.ErrorCode = RA.ErrorCode and A.Id = RA.Id

SELECT * FROM #TempErrorCode order by RankVal
```

The output is as shown below

```
id  ErrorCode         ErrorCount               RankVal
1   module_position   A1_16__1                   1
2   head_id HZ0C1     000877                     1
3   start_dt          2018-09-10 00:18:27        1
4   module_position   A2_16__1                   2
5   head_id HZ0C1     000878                     2
6   start_dt          2018-09-10 00:18:27        2
```

[**Live Demo <> Rank Update**](https://rextester.com/PSNT18425)